# Don't do any fills in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have a macro that will draw several things in a TikZ picture using some styles I defined, which include fills:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
mystyle1/.style={fill=red,font={\bfseries}},
mystyle2/.style={fill=yellow,draw=blue}
}
\newcommand{\doit}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mystyle1,circle]at(0,0){Text1};
  \node[mystyle2,rectangle] at (3,0){Text2};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
Foo

\doit

bar
\end{document}
```

Which looks like

[image: have]

How can I tell TikZ, before or after the `\tikzset`, to

> don't do the fills but everything else

without redefining all the styles? (Here it's only two, but in my real applications it's many and they may change.)

So, the result should look like this:

[image: want]

I thought, that something like

```
\tikzset{every node/.append style={fill=none}}
```

should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be to define a style `myfill` which can be switched on and off.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{myfill/.style={fill=#1}}

\tikzset{%
mystyle1/.style={myfill=red,font={\bfseries}},
mystyle2/.style={myfill=yellow,draw=blue}
}
\newcommand{\doit}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mystyle1,circle]at(0,0){Text1};
  \node[mystyle2,rectangle] at (3,0){Text2};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
Foo

\doit

bar

\tikzset{myfill/.style=}
\doit

off
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you allow for an optional Parameter to the `\doit` macro with which you can specify other options.. So `\doit` produces the first image and `\doit[fill=none]` produces the second:

[image]

If you want more flexibility you can have two optional parameters to control the options for the circle and rectangle separately.  So the third option below was produced with:

```
\doit[fill=orange, draw=blue, ultra thick][fill=green!50, draw=magenta, ultra thick]
```

[image]

### Notes:

- I used [the `xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to provide the macro that allows for two optional parameters. If you do not want to include an additional package, there are probably other ways to accomplish this.

### Code: One Optional Parameter

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
    mystyle1/.style={fill=red,font={\bfseries}},
    mystyle2/.style={fill=yellow,draw=blue}
}

\newcommand{\doit}[1][]{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mystyle1, circle, #1] at (0,0){Text1};
  \node[mystyle2, rectangle, #1] at (3,0){Text2};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
Foo

\doit

\doit[fill=none]


bar
\end{document}
```

### Code: Two Optional Parameters

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
    mystyle1/.style={fill=red,font={\bfseries}},
    mystyle2/.style={fill=yellow,draw=blue}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\doit}{O{} O{}}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mystyle1, circle, #1] at (0,0){Text1};
  \node[mystyle2, rectangle, #2] at (3,0){Text2};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
Foo

\doit

\doit[fill=none][fill=none]

\doit[fill=orange, draw=blue, ultra thick][fill=green!50, draw=magenta, ultra thick]

bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted a solution *without* redefining the styles.

Comment: Perhaps I am not fully understanding your comment, but I am not redefining the styles, just adding to them as needed.  Your complete style is applied then only what you specify in the optional parameter is overwritten.

Comment: I have made no changes to `mystyle1` and `mystyle2`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, confused the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to inspiration from Thomas F. Sturm and Peter Grill I have found a nice solution for myself:

Just redefine the `fill`-style:

```
\tikzset{fill/.style={}}
```

Please comment, if this is an acceptable way or should be put into `l2tabu`.